# Marginal effects from estat mfx after asclogit

Tags: stata

I am trying to understand how Stata calculates both the probability that an alternative is selected and the marginal effect calculated that the mean when I `estat mfx` after estimating a McFadden / conditional logit model using `asclogit`.

For example:

```
asclogit H t, case(ID) alternatives(AQ) casevars(Medicaid) /// 
basealternative(1) vce(cluster Medicaid) 

estat mfx, varlist(Medicaid)
```

My goal is to re-create the results by estimating the same model using the `clogit` and manually calculating the equivalent marginal effects. I am able to reproduce the conditional logit estimates generated by `asclogit` using `clogit` but I get stuck reproducing the post estimation calculations.

I have not been able to re-produce computed probability of each alternative being selected, which from reading the documentation for `estat mfx` I learned is evaluated at the value that is labeled `X` in the table output.

Here are the `estat` probability figures:

[image]

In case the picture didn't come out:

```
. matrix baseline = r(pr_1)\r(pr_2)\r(pr_3)\r(pr_4)\r(pr_5)

. matrix list baseline

baseline[5,1]
           c1
r1  .04077232
r2  .15206384
r3  .01232535
r4  .10465885
r5  .69017964
```

Keep in mind that the variables beginning with `Valpha` and `VMedicaid` are case specific variables I created for the `clogit` command. They are respectively the intercept and an indicator for Medicaid coverage.

Here is what I have:

```
clogit H t  Valpha* i.VMedicaid_2 i.VMedicaid_3 i.VMedicaid_4 i.VMedicaid_5 , ///
group(ID) vce(cluster Medicaid) 

* Reproducing probability an alternative selected calculated by estat mfx

// calculate covariate means to plug into probability calculations

local V t Valpha* VMedicaid_* Medicaid

foreach var of varlist `V' {
    summarize `var'
    scalar `var'_MN = r(mean)
}

// alternative specific ZB
scalar zb = _b[t]*t_MN


// numerators attempt 1

foreach j of numlist 2/5 {
    scalar XB`j' = exp(zb + (_b[Valpha_`j']*Valpha_`j'_MN) + ///
    (_b[1.VMedicaid_`j']*VMedicaid_`j'_MN))

    di "this is `j': " XB`j'
}

// numerators attempt 2, documentation for estat mfx said that probably was 
// evaluated with Medicaid= 0.68 which is the Medicaid coverage rate across cases 
// rather than the mean of the various VMedicaid_ variables are used to estimate 
// clogit. Replaced intercept mean with 1

foreach j of numlist 2/5 {
    scalar XB`j' = exp(zb + (_b[Valpha_`j']) + (_b[1.VMedicaid_`j' *Medicaid_MN))
    di "this is `j': " XB`j'
}

scalar XB1 =exp(zb)

// denominator
scalar DNM  = XB1+ XB2+ XB3+ XB4 + XB5

// Baseline 
foreach j of numlist 1/5 {
    scalar PRB`j' = XB`j'/DNM
    di "The probability of choosing hospital `j' is: " PRB`j'
}
```

The results I get are the following:

```
The probability of choosing hospital 1 is: .14799075
The probability of choosing hospital 2 is: .21019437
The probability of choosing hospital 3 is: .09046377
The probability of choosing hospital 4 is: .18383085
The probability of choosing hospital 5 is: .36752026
```

Comment: It is difficult for people to look into your question without providing a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for the tip and the revisions Pearly, I made an example using choice data set that's available online which replicated my problems. I'm not sure how to add it to my original question though.

Comment: Press the 'edit' link at the end of the question and copy and paste your data in there?

Comment: Use `dataex` to create the example dataset. `help dataex`.